# Write permission denied on Apache2 / Debian 9

Tags: php, debian, prestashop, lamp

I have a VPS with apache2 php-fpm running prestashop, it's been working for years, but out of a sudden, prestashop is having trouble with permissions.

Apache's user and group is set to "www-data" the same as all the files and folders in the www folder. All permissions are set to 755 and 644 but cache/smarty (Had to set those to 777 so the store could keep working.)

I've checked that its a permissions problem as prestashop cant regenerate the .htaccess file from the backoffice (unless I set it to 777).

I'm not sure what to check or what can I supply to you. Any help is welcome. Thank you all for your time.

**EDIT**

I've been checking the processes for "apache2" and all of them were run by www-data.

Steadweb told me to check php-fpm, seems like thats the problem. But I'm not sure where to change that.

[image]

Comment: What about setting the ownership of the `.htaccess` file to `www-data` user / group?

Comment: every single file and folder in the www folder is set to www-data:www-data

Comment: What user does php-fpm run as?

Comment: Just checked and edited the question

Comment: It's not advised to give PHP full access for security reasons, but this is your issue. I'll provide an answer shortly on how to configure php-fpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on `Debian 9.7`, edit the following file:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

And find the following, where `user` / `group` is declared. Update as follows:

```
...
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

You'll need to restart the `apache` / `php-fpm` processes

```
ressystemctl restart php7.0-fpm apache2
```

#### Notes

- This is bad practice, as you're opening up privileges for `php-fpm`. I'd make sure that specific directories / files have write permissions.
- Set your web directory to ownership of your user `chown -R user:www-data /path/to/website`
- Use the following commands to set the permissions for directories / files for you website

```
cd /path/to/website
find -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

- *Then, open up **specific** files / directories that require writable access.*